# Auto guess Profit/Loss from django and react

Tags: reactjs, django, redux, django-rest-framework, react-redux

I'm creating and analysis website using Yahoo Finance API.

`models.py`

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    money_to_invest = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    stock_price = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    profit_or_loss = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`serializers.py`

```
class StockSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        fields = '__all__'
```

`views.py`

```
class StockViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Stock.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StockSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, ]
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication, ]

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Stock.objects.filter(author=user).all()
```

`React Part`

```
const onInputChange = (e) => setformData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
```

```
<div className="form-group">
<input
className="form-control"
type="text"
placeholder="Profit or Loss"
name="profit_or_loss"
value={money_to_invest > regular_market_price ? 'Profit' : 'Loss'}
onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
readOnly
/>
</div>
```

In `profit_or_loss` field want to auto save value `Profit` or `Loss`. if `money_to_invest` is greater than `stock_price` than is is `Profit`. How it can be possible through `Django` and `React`. I'm also using `Redux` for state management.

Comment: Can you include all the Django, React, and Redux code if you think it's relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to *store* this in a field: the field is functionally completely dependent on other fields, so this would introduce *data duplication*. You can annotate the `Stock` model with a [**`Case`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#django.db.models.expressions.Case) when you need this:

```
from django.db.models import Case, F, Value, When

Stock.objects.annotate(
    profit_or_loss=Case(
        When(money_to_invest__gt=F('stock_price'), then=Value('Profit')),
        default=Value('Loss')
    )
)
```